# safari history.plist file missing in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, safari, jailbreak

I want to access safari history file programmatically,after going to several questions here I found that safari history is stored at the following path: `/var/mobile/Library/Safari/History.plist`, but I am not able to see the History.plist file,only safari bookmarks related files are present inside Safari directory.

Does the History.plist file has been moved to some other path in iOS7. 
I have checked it on jailbroken  iPhone 5S(iOS 7.1.1) and iPhone 5C(iOS 7.1.2) using iFile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to:

`/var/mobile/Applications/-safari app identifier-/Library/Safari/History.plist`

For finding the full path of safari (or any other system/user application) you could check a plist named `com.apple.mobile.installation.plist`. This file is located at `/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist`. This plist file contains what we want. The plist is something like below:

```
-Root
    ...
    +System (Dictionary)
    +User (Dictionary)
    ...
```

Safari is a system application so inside the system dictionary we could see a key named `com.apple.mobilesafari` which is a key for a dictionary too. This dictionary contains a string keyed `Path` that is what you want. As you can see the path to any other application could be known by knowing the application type and bundle identifier. So your code should be something like this:

```
- (NSString*) safariPath {
    return [self applicaitonFullPath:@"com.apple.mobilesafari" appType:@"System"];
}

- (NSString*) applicaitonFullPath:(NSString*)bundleIdentifier appType:(NSString*)appType {
    //appType shoud be `System` or `User` case sensitive!!
    NSDictionary *mobileInstallationDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist"];
    return mobileInstallationDict[appType][bundleIdentifier][@"Path"];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hamed,that was a great explanation and solution worked for me.

Comment: don know why my changes are rejected,but still i want to mention that bindleIdentifier should be bundleIdentifier and instead of using [type] the key should be [appType].

Comment: @user3932883 Thanks for the edits you mentioned. I corrected them:)

Comment: Turns out the file com.apple.mobile.installation.plist  no longer exists iOS 8 and later :( https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Com.apple.mobile.installation.plist

Answer (score 0):

Check at this path :

```
/private/var/mobile/Applications/Library/Safari/History.plist
```

Comment: Thanks,i got the History.plist file but the problem is that the path is /var/mobile/Applications/<app identifier>/Library/Safari/History.plist; and this app identifier is different in different iphones;in that case how can i hard code the path in my code as this path is dependent on app identifier.

Comment: You can't. You have to create the path dynamicaly inside you app. And can you mark the answer accepted please ;) ?

Comment: Thanks,but can you please tell me how to dynamically get this path  or can i directly use the path listed by you?

Comment: kindly tell me the code to get this path dynamically

Comment: Sorry but it was the suggestion but don't have the code and don't have time now to write it. Take a look on google on how to retrieve path to library.